# Record display but i can update it in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone i'm able to display my record by passing an id by query string to another page, but i'm not  able to update it, the problem is that when i click on update nothing happen, it return me a blank page, and there is no printed error, can someone help me please?

```
  <?php
   require 'db2.php';
   $id = null;
     if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

 $dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
 $q = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MovieID = '$id' ");
   while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
     {   
    $title = $r["Title"];
    $tag = $r["Tag"];
    $year = $r["YEAR"];
    $cast = $r["Cast"];
    $comment = $r["Comment"];
    $IDBM = $r["IMDB"];
}


}
```

At this stage, the code display every information i need , the stage below is where i'm having a problem, i'm not able to get the id against and make the update when click on update button

```
elseif (!empty($_POST) and !empty($_GET['id']) ) {


    // keep track post values
    $cast = $_POST['cast'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $comment =$_POST['comment'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];
      $tag = $_POST['tags'];
     $IDBM = $_POST['idbm'];
    $cast = htmlspecialchars($cast);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($cast)) {
        $castError = 'Please enter Cast';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($title)) {
        $titleError = 'Please enter Title';
        $valid = false;
    }
      if (empty($comment)) {
        $commentError = 'Please enter Comment';
        $valid = false;
    }


    if ($valid) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {

                                 mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE movie SET Title='$title',Year = '$year',Cast='$cast',Cover='$actual_image_name',Tag='$tag',Comment='$comment',IMDB ='$IDBM' WHERE MovieID=".$id);
                                header ("Location: index.php");
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing the id to next page? hidden input field? query string? How does the update form (html) look like?

Comment: @NawedKhan, query string, i have a button update on it, when click update, it should make a validation check before to check if any record is missing then used the id against from the query string to make the update, displaying the information from the query string work but update not

Comment: Catch and check result of mysqli_query. If it is FALSE, there is an error, else it should be TRUE. 
http://us1.php.net/mysqli_query
And if there is an error, you can see it using
echo mysqli_error($dbc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, when you get a blank page, check your error log. Or if you're lazy, add this at the begining of your file to get error messages.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
```

It's hard to say, but just looking at your code quickly, I see a problem with  your mixup of `$_GET` and `$_POST`. From what I gather, since your `SELECT`works, you send data in `$_GET`, and your `UPDATE` block is only executed if you have `$_POST` data.

Change your html `<form method="get">` for `<form method="post">`

And change your `select` block to check `if( !empty($_POST['id'])) {`